# view is not displayed as expected

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

```
private function sendmail($userid, $reportcontent,$email){
        //if($this->Session->read($this->_userName))
        {
            $this->loadModel('EwtMailtemplate');
            $this->loadModel('EwtUser');
            $this->loadModel('EwtSetting');
            $this->autoRender = false;

            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $userinfo = $this->EwtUser->read(null, $userid);
            $fullname = $userinfo['EwtUser']['fullname'];
            $lastname = $userinfo['EwtUser']['lastname'];
            $mailtempl = $userinfo['EwtUser']['mailtempl'];
            if ($mailtempl == 0) {
                $mailtempl = 1;
            }

            $setting = $this->EwtSetting->find('first');
            $mailhost = $setting['EwtSetting']['mailhost'];
            $mailuser = $setting['EwtSetting']['mailuser'];
            $mailpass = $setting['EwtSetting']['mailpass'];
            //$reportmail = $setting['EwtSetting']['reportmail'];
            $reportmail=$email;
            $bodymail = $this->EwtMailtemplate->read(null, $mailtempl);
            //$header = $bodymail['EwtMailtemplate']['header'];
            //$footer = $bodymail['EwtMailtemplate']['footer'];
            //$title = $bodymail['EwtMailtemplate']['title'];
            $subject="New login password for working time system";
            //$subject = $lastname . " " . str_replace("[date]", $date, $title);
            //$header = str_replace("[lastname]", $lastname, $header);
            //$header = str_replace("[date]", $date, $header);
            //$footer = str_replace("[lastname]", $lastname, $footer);

            //$content = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset =utf-8" /></head><body>'.$header ."<br />" . $reportcontent . "<br />" .  $footer . '</body></html>';

            $content = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset =utf-8" /></head><body>'."<br />".$reportcontent."<br />".'</body></html>';

            $this->Email->to = $reportmail;
            $this->Email->charset = 'UTF-8';
            $this->Email->from = sprintf("%s <%s>", $fullname, $mailuser);
            $this->Email->replyto = sprintf("%s <%s>", $fullname, $mailuser);
            $this->Email->subject = $subject;
            $this->Email->sendAs ='html';
            $smtp = array(
                        'port'=>25,
                        'host'=>$mailhost,
                        'timeout'=>99,
                        'username'=>$mailuser,
                        'password'=>$mailpass
            );
            $this->Email->smtpOptions = $smtp;
            $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';

            $bool=($this->Email->send($content))?true:false;

            $smtp_error = $this->Email->smtpError;
            if (strlen($smtp_error)>0){
                //$this->Session->setflash($smtp_errors);
                $bool=false;
            }
            if(!$bool)
            {
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'userexists'));
            }
            return $bool;
        }
    }
```

I use that function to send an email to the address provided by the user. After the button is pressed, a view is displayed, I call this view newpassword, (created with the same view name newpassword.ctp). The controller function looks as follows,

```
    function newpassword()
        {
            $this->loadSkinForAction();
            $result=$this->EwtUser->get_user_from_email($_POST['email']);

            if(!empty($result))
            {
                $userid = $result[0]['ewt_users']['id'];
                $password=$this->EwtUser->get_and_change_user_password($_POST['email']);            
                $mail="Your new password is: ".$password."<br/>Please use it for next login.<br/>You are recommended to change this password again in your 'Personal Profile' section.";
                $bool = $this->sendmail($userid,$mail,$_POST['email']);

            }
            else
            {

                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'userexists'));
            }
        }
```

And the form is used to provoke the above function is written as follows,

```
    <div id="form_pwd" style="display:none;">      
            <form method="POST" action="/working_time/ewt_users/newpassword" id="new_pwd">
                <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="175px"><label for="email">Your email address</label></td>                
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="35"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The trouble I am into right now is that the first-most function does as what I suppose it to do but at the last line after the mail is sent, the view (newpassword.ctp) is not displayed at all. If any of you could provide some spots over where the mistakes i made are, I am truly grateful. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say the view isn't displayed at all, do you mean that the output is a blank screen? The thing that jumps out to me immediately is the redirect to the `userexists` action in the `sendmail()` method - try replacing this with a debug statement to see whether it is executing that line.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$this->autoRender` to `false`. I think this will set it for the current process, thus invalidating the calling functions (newpassword()) autoRender also.

I think you are approaching this the wrong way IMHO.

Comment: I might add, you are defying quite a few cakephp conventions in your code. I would suggest spending some more time reading the book.